# How to remove part of the string after specific word in Python

Tags: python

I get API-responses as a string which can be in two different formats:

1) `This is a message. <br><br>This message was created by Jimmy.`

2)

```
This is a message.

Text can be in the new row.

This message was created by Jimmy.
```

I want to remove text "This message was created by ['name']" from every message. Expected result:

> This is a message.

This is what I have tried:
`modified_message = re.search('(.+?)<br><br>', message).group(1)`

It works with the 1) example, but it doesn't with 2) of course.

How could I filter the text off from 2) example as it is multiline string or could it be possible with one expression?

Comment: please post your expected input and output, this seems little confusing

Comment: Please paste your code / output / error if any.

Comment: @akashkarothiya Added.

Comment: @DineshPundkar Added

Comment: @MMakela please try below regex

Comment: I would like to know why the downvotes? I couldn't find similar question posted here before.

Comment: @MMakela paste your code in your question.

Comment: @Trimax Yes I have already done that. My regex expression is there and message formations which are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this.
Added code to handle multiline strings.

```
import re
data1 = "This is a message. <br><br>This message was created by Jimmy."
data2 = """
This is a message.

This message was created by Jimmy.
"""
print "First case..."
print data1
output1 = re.findall('(.*?)This message was created',data1,re.DOTALL)[0].replace("<br>",'')
print "Output is ..."
print(output1)
print "----------------------------------------"
print "Second Case..."
print data2
print "Output is ..."
output2 = re.findall('(.*?)This message was created',data1,re.DOTALL)[0].replace("<br>",'')
print(output2)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users>python main.py
First case...
This is a message. <br><br>This message was created by Jimmy.
Output is ...
This is a message.
----------------------------------------
Second Case...

This is a message.

This message was created by Jimmy.

Output is ...

This is a message.
```

Comment: How this can work, if "This is a message" -text changes in every string?

Comment: Found out that if the message contains number, text before the number will be removed too. For example a message: `This 1 is a message. <br><br>This message was created by Jimmy.` -> output will be `is a message.`

Comment: @MMakela : Updated the regex in above code sample. Please check.